# Google Cloud Endpoints oauth

Tags: google-app-engine, oauth-2.0, outlook, google-cloud-endpoints

I am new to cloud programming and will be making a GAE app with Cloud Endpoints.

I would like to use Oauth, but for Microsoft accounts as well as Google accounts.

I am having a hard time finding a definitive answer in the docs. I have read posts that are 3-4 years old stating that Cloud Endpoints only supports Oauth with Google accounts, but is this still the case?

Comment: You can use [AuthO](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/authentication-method#auth0) as it _..authenticates and authorizes apps and APIs regardless of identity provider, platform, stack and device..._ Please see the link and tell me if it answers your question.

Comment: It does, thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: I will write an answer based on this comment. Please accept it so that the community knows the issue is solved. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You can go to [Choosing an Authentication Method](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/authentication-method#auth0). There is a section titled [Auth0](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/authentication-method#auth0) which states:

> [Auth0](https://auth0.com/) authenticates and authorizes apps and APIs **regardless of
> identity provider, platform, stack and device.**
>
> Auth0 supports a large number of providers and the [Security Assertion
> Markup Language](https://wiki.oasis-open.org/security/FrontPage) specification. It provides backend services, SDKs and
> user interface libraries for authenticating users in web and mobile
> apps......
>
> .....

This might be what you need. Hope this helps

Comment: once i protected my endpoint, it is protecting also the pod, in case i can't do ervice mesh, service 2 service (clusterip) communication, how can it exclude the security over service mesh calls ?